# Variable values are not substituting at run time in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am newbie to AngularJs. Here is my code. In this i am trying to build the url by getting system date. But the values are not substituting at the time of jsonp request. I don't know Why.

Here when i try to add parameters manually. i am getting the values. But when i try to use the variables i am not getting the output.

```
    $scope.getCurrentMonthData = function(){

        $scope.date = new Date();
        $scope.startday = 1;
        $scope.currentday = $scope.date.getDate()+1;
        $scope.month = $scope.date.getMonth()+1;
        $scope.year = $scope.date.getFullYear();
        $scope.start= $scope.year+'/'+$scope.month+'/'+$scope.startday;

        $scope.end = $scope.year+'/'+$scope.month+'/'+$scope.currentday;

        $scope.url1 = $rootScope.ApiWeatherHost+'/climo/v1/actuals/'+$scope.location_key+'.json?start='+$scope.start+'&end='+$scope.end+'&apikey='+$rootScope.ApiKey;

        $scope.url2 = $rootScope.ApiWeatherHost+'/climo/v1/records/'+$scope.location_key+'.json?start='+$scope.start+'&end='+$scope.end+'&apikey='+$rootScope.ApiKey;

        $scope.url3 = $rootScope.ApiWeatherHost+'/climo/v1/normals/'+$scope.location_key+'.json?start='+$scope.start+'&end='+$scope.end+'&apikey='+$rootScope.ApiKey;

        $http.jsonp($scope.url1).then(function(msg){
          console.log(msg.data);
        });
       $http.jsonp($scope.url2).then(function(msg){
          console.log(msg.data);
        });
        $http.jsonp($scope.url3).then(function(msg){
          console.log(msg.data);
        });

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are defining `location_key` so I don't know for certain if that is your problem, but when I run the following code, I see all three URL's created.

Have you checked to see if there is an error when you attempt to make those requests?

```js
(function($scope, $rootScope){

        $scope.date = new Date();
        $scope.startday = 1;
        $scope.currentday = $scope.date.getDate()+1;
        $scope.month = $scope.date.getMonth()+1;
        $scope.year = $scope.date.getFullYear();
        $scope.start= $scope.year+'/'+$scope.month+'/'+$scope.startday;

        $scope.end = $scope.year+'/'+$scope.month+'/'+$scope.currentday;

        $scope.url1 = $rootScope.ApiWeatherHost+'/climo/v1/actuals/'+$scope.location_key+'.json?start='+$scope.start+'&end='+$scope.end+'&apikey='+$rootScope.ApiKey;

        $scope.url2 = $rootScope.ApiWeatherHost+'/climo/v1/records/'+$scope.location_key+'.json?start='+$scope.start+'&end='+$scope.end+'&apikey='+$rootScope.ApiKey;

        $scope.url3 = $rootScope.ApiWeatherHost+'/climo/v1/normals/'+$scope.location_key+'.json?start='+$scope.start+'&end='+$scope.end+'&apikey='+$rootScope.ApiKey;

        var output = $('#output');
        $('<div>').text($scope.url1).appendTo(output);
        $('<div>').text($scope.url2).appendTo(output);
        $('<div>').text($scope.url3).appendTo(output);
       

}({}, {ApiWeatherHost:'www.fake-api.com', ApiKey:'12345'}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='output'></div>
```

Comment: Ya i am also getting this. but when i try to send that url to JSNOP..
it's not working.. i don't know why.?

Comment: @mani - What does it say in the dev tools console? If you inspect the HTTP response that comes back does it contain an error?

Comment: The Output is coming. But It's not a JSONP Format. Its giving only JSON Format. Some times it also giving the JSONP Format as output. I don't know about this. I check with server side people also. There is no problem from their end.

Comment: Is this a public API? I don't want you to publish your API Key, but perhaps if I could write my own code to hit the API I could see what was going on?

Comment: No its not Public API.? It's a Private API Keys.